# Game crashes when I open my friend's tower

Tags: tiny-tower

Everytime I go to my friend's tower, no matter how many times I delete and add it again, it always says it was opened a day ago, but my friend tipped me 30 minutes ago. When I go there, it only shows the lobby and a floor for construction. She showed me a picture and she has 3 floors, since she started playing a couple days ago. But when I go there, Bitizens move for one second until it crashes. Everything stops except for the music, and I can't get out of it without completely closing the app. What is going on?

Comment: Sounds like a typical game bug, post the issue on the app's page and they might be able to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the game is bad it updating and doesn't register that she doesn't still have one floor, get the game thinks she has one floor then it won't know which floor to put your character on and will therefore crash. As for why the game isn't updating, I'm not exactly sure.